# Характер посылаемых клиенту данных

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Встал вопрос: как разумнее оповестить клиента сервером о характере посылаемых данных, например, надо в случае ошибки, к примеру, выводить данные в одном элементе, а в случае успеха - в другом.

Я подумываю применить JSON в качестве ответа, где свойство `type` будет характеризовать тип сообщения, а `content` - его содержимое. Но мне кажется, данная модель неблагоприятна скажется на производительности, так как вместо привычных `echo` надо будет накапливать ответ в переменной, а потом обрабатывать с помощью `json_encode()`. Если кто-то имеет опыт решения подобных проблем, подскажите, в какую сторону смотреть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Привычные echo" работают медленнее непривычного буфера. И неважно, используете ли вы ob-функции или просто пишете все в переменную.
По поводу вывода данных в json: сохраняйте все в массив, потом применяйте json_encode() и echo + exit(если надо). Пример:

```
if($_GET['type'] == 'ajax'){
    $data = array();
    if($a = $obj->get_some_data()){
        $data['type'] = 'success';
        $data['msg'] = $a;
    }
    else{
        $data['type'] = 'error';
        $data['msg'] = $obj->err_type;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
}
```

Собственно, если вы выводите верстку через множественные echo, вышеприведенный код может и не сработать - выведет полстраницы + json.

Comment: Ну так я понимаю, можно сделать так : создать объект в котором будет в параметре массива накапливаться данные плюс тип сообщения, а уже для удобства в деструкторе использовать json_encode() Ну и разумеется избегать всех echo, var_dump, print и пр.

И, конечно, огромное спасибо за отличный ответ!

Comment: @ling - Еще вопрос, посмотрел мельком ob-функции(за их упоминание особое спасибо) и понял, с их помощью, а точнее с помощью ob_get_contents() можно перенаправить все echo в нужную переменную. Догадка верна?

Comment: @culebre, верна.

Answer (score 0):

> так как вместо привычных echo надо
> будет накапливать ответ в переменной

То есть, Вы думаете, что мешать код и представление - это очень быстро, удобно и красиво?

Comment: Это, я так понял ответ, по еврейски! Нет, я так не думаю, но поясните точнее, где я его мешаю я буду только рад.

Answer (score 0):

Совет из опыта:
Не спрашивайте, если работает, и не выглядит по-индийски - пишите. Это ваш код, вас за него не упрекнут. Сегодня напишите так, завтра познаете новое, оптимизируйте. Самообучение тут полезнее советов со стороны: советовать вам будут все то, что нравится и удобнее им.

Дерзайте

Answer (score 0):

Я использовал такой путь:

1. Отказ от прямого ( относительно ) AJAX из кода - всё через универсальный метод
2. Доп. служебный контейнер для ответов сервера
3. Предобработчик ответов

Т.е. что-то типа:

```
Ajax = function (url, data, fn, scope ){
  /* Делаем запрос */
  if ( response.type == 'error' ){ /* универсальная обработка*/ }
  else fn.apply( scope, [ response.content ] ); 
}
```

На данном уровне обрабатываются только ошибки типа "ограничение прав", "авторазлогин при неактивности".

В реальной ситуации - это будет достаточно сложная ф-я...

P.S: Позже прочитал, что вы практически так-же и хотите)))